# Setting up associations and forms for my Quora Like Rails App

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nameerror

Hello I am trying to build a quora like app using ruby on rails. I have decided to call my questions pins in this case, and my answers are still answers. However When I try to answer a question I get this error:

```
NameError at /pins/2 undefined local variable or method `answer' for #<#<Class:0x007fc934792fc0>:0x007fc93428fb18>
```

I am using Devise as well. Here is my associations thus far.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 has_many :pins
 has_many :answers
 has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "400x400", :thumb => "200x200" },    :     :default_url => "avatar/missing.jpg"
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Here is my Pin Model

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :description, presence: true
  has_many :answers
end
```

Here is my Answer Model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :pin
 belongs_to :user
 validates :description, presence: true
end
```

Here is my Pins Controller

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
  @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)
end

def show
end

def new
 @pin = current_user.pins.build
end

def edit
end

def create
  @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
 if @pin.save
   redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
 else
   render action: 'new'
 end
end

def update
  if @pin.update(pin_params)
   redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
 else
   render action: 'edit'
 end
end

def destroy
  @pin.destroy
 redirect_to pins_url
end

private
 # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
 def set_pin
   @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
 end

 def correct_user
   @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
   redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
 end

 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def pin_params
   params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
 end
end
```

and Here is my Answer Controller

```
     class AnswersController < ApplicationController
       before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
       before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
       before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

       def create
        @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
        @answer = @pin.answers.create(answer_params)
        redirect_to pin_path(@pin)
       end

        private
          def set_answer
            @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
          end

         def correct_user
           @answer = current_user.answers.find_by(id: params[:id])
           redirect_to answers_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @answer.nil?
         end

          def answer_params
            params.require(:answer).permit(:description)
          end
   end
```

And Here is my show form 
       <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
       <%= notice %>

```
   <p>
    <strong>Description:</strong>
    <%= @pin.description %>
   </p>

   <h2>Answers</h2>
    <% @pin.answers.each do |comment| %>
      <p>
         <strong>Answer:</strong>
         <%= answer.description %>
      </p>
     <% end %>

   <h2>Answer this questions:</h2>
  <%= form_for([@pin, @pin.answers.build]) do |f| %>
   <p>
     <%= f.label :description %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :description %>
   </p>
    <p>
     <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(@pin) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
```

Could anyone tell me the problem. Thanks in an advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in view:

```
<% @pin.answers.each do |comment| %> # Here you have "comment"
  <p>
    <strong>Answer:</strong>
    <%= answer.description %> # And here "answer", change it to "comment" or vice versa
  </p>
<% end %>
```